# Login issue with Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, login

I use Stack Exchange application on Android 4.3. I can receive notification and see my questions/answers, so I can say I'm logged in. However, when I try to make an action, like vote up/down, I receive following dialog box:

[image: dialog box]

And if I press "Join Site", next message appears:

[image: "you're already a member of" message]

> You're already a member of Stack Overflow

I'm missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: This is still an issue. I just deleted my report when I was pointed to this question. For added info I am using Android  4.1.2. Restarting the phone seems to fix the problem. Although it seems bad design if you have to reboot after joining a new StackExchange site.

Comment: Happens in iOS app as well http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236960/registering-to-a-new-site-after-asking-a-question-is-broken-on-the-ios-app-versi

Comment: Happening on android 6.0.1 BlackBerry PRIV too